# How to update a RadioButton's text when something is typed in a TextView field

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView field named tvFillIn that should update the text of a RadioButton named rbZeroToN every time something is typed into the TextView field tvFillIn. This is what I first came up with:

```
tvFillIn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            rbZeroToN.setText("0-" + tvFillIn.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            rbZeroToN.setText("0-" + tvFillIn.getText());
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. How should I solve this instead? Any ideas?

Comment: remove the code from onTextChanged & beforeTextChanged. Just add this to afterTextChanged==> rbZeroToN.setText("0-" + s.toString()); I guess,this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, I have checked it

```
your_editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                rb.setText(your_editText.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Not checked with RadioGroup but only with 1 RadioButton

Comment: well there is no need to take text by 'getText()', what about arg0.. just call it 'toString()'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not seem to work for me. Does it matter that the TextView I use is a Number (Signed) one?

Comment: I just did a few things wrong to get the input, thanks for the help, it works now! :)